# SEH Eceptions - generating and handling

Tags: c++, structured-exception

I want to generate and handle exceptions (SEH).
How can I write a code that will lead to an "illegal instruction"-exception?

Comment: "c++, Windows, Linux" spot the odd one out...

Comment: Unless something weird has happened recently, SEH is a Microsoft-specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <cstdio>

::DWORD FilterFunction(::DWORD const _exception_code)
{
    if(EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION == _exception_code)
    {
        ::std::printf("filtered\n");
        return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
    }
    else
    {
        ::std::printf("not filtered\n");
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
    }
}

int main()
{
    __try
    {
        ::std::printf("trying...\n");
        ::RaiseException
        (
            EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION // exception id
        ,   0 // continuable exception
        ,   0 // args count
        ,   nullptr // args
        );             // no arguments
        ::std::printf("finished trying\n");
    }
    __except(FilterFunction(GetExceptionCode()))
    {
        ::std::printf("exception handled\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> trying...
>
> filtered
>
> exception handled

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Yes, it's clear that Raise Exception can be used . But in the task it is necessary to describe the code that will lead to the EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION

Answer (score 0):

You can raise a structured exception in Windows with:

`RaiseException(EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION, EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE, 0, nullptr);`

Reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680552%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply Yes, it's clear that Raise Exception can be used . But in the task it is necessary to describe the code that will lead to the EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION

Comment: @j12 interesting assignment. There is no intrinsic for this AFAIA, so 2 options: 1 - inline assembly, 2 - Compile with cpu extensions you know the host computer does not have (e.g. SSE2 etc)